# Reuse Ionic Components in Ionic 3 and Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this ionic list

```html
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let friend of (friendsObs|async)">
    <h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And I want to extract the ion-item part as a component so i can reuse it somewhere else. But the following doesn't work as I want it.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'friend-item',
  template: '
    <ion-item>
      <h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
    </ion-item>'
})
export class FriendItemComponent {
  @Input() friend: Friend;
}
```

```html
<ion-list>
  <friend-item *ngFor="let friend of (friendsObs|async)" [friend]='friend'>
</ion-list>
```

This was working but i later found out the content is being wrapped in  and the layout is not as expected, like following.

```html
<ion-list>
  <friend-item>
    <ion-item>
      <h2>Friend's Name</h2>
    </ion-item>'
  </friend-item>
</ion-list>
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Did u find the solution for this? I am into similar situation

Answer (score 2):

The template string in your `@Component` decorator is not a valid string. If you want to do it as a multi-line string, you should use the ES6 template literals (see [template literals on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

That means you have to use back ticks instead of single or double quotes:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'friend-item',
  template: `
    <ion-item>
      <h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
    </ion-item>`
})
export class FriendItemComponent {
  @Input() friend: Friend;
}
```